# Auto login after registration Spring Boot 3/Spring security 6

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

My question is targeted mainly to Spring Boot 3.x/Spring Security 6.x but it may apply to older versions too. I've a small trivial project with form login. Here is a sample configuration.

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.
        ...
        formLogin().
        loginPage("/users/login").
        ...
    return http.build();
  }

  @Bean
  public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(UserRepository userRepository) {
    return new AppUserDetailsService(userRepository);
  }

  @Bean
  public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
  }
}
```

Nothing special indeed and it works totally fine. I also have a registration form. It also works fine and the user is created in the DB correctly. It can log in afterwards. So far so good.

The last thing I want to do is to automatically login the user right after the registration.  In earlier Srping versions this worked with similar code, maybe inspired from [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-auto-login-user-after-registration):

```
@Override
  public void createAccount(UserRegistrationDTO userRegistrationDTO) {

    UserEntity userEntity = new UserEntity();
    userEntity.
        setFirstName(userRegistrationDTO.getFirstName()).
        setLastName(userRegistrationDTO.getLastName()).
        setEmail(userRegistrationDTO.getEmail()).
        setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(userRegistrationDTO.getPassword()));
    userRepository.save(userEntity);

    var userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userRegistrationDTO.getEmail());
    Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
      userDetails,
      userDetails.getPassword(),
      userDetails.getAuthorities()
    );

    SecurityContextHolder.
        getContext().
        setAuthentication(authentication);
  }
```

This no longer works in 3.x/6.x

My guess is that I need to use the `AuthenticationManager` instead, but I'm not sure how to inject the proper local `AuthenticationManager` and for which security filter chain. I even cannot figure out how to use `AuthenticationManagerResolver<HttpServletRequest>` if this is the way to resolve it...

I've manged to implement the feature by using `HttpServletRequest.login(userName, password)` which delegates to the `AuthenticationManager` internally in the spring context and perhaps does millions of other things. But I have a feeling that I'm doing something very wrong..

What is the correct way to implement this trivial feature?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all many thanks to Marcus Hert da Coregio for pointing me in the right direction. Indeed this is a breaking change in Spring security 6 described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/session-management.html#_require_explicit_saving_of_securitycontextrepository). The security context repository though is not `HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository` anymore but rather `DelegatingSecurityContextRepository`. This is described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/session-management.html#_change_httpsessionsecuritycontextrepository_to_delegatingsecuritycontextrepository).

What I did is to expose the `DelegatingSecurityContextRepository` as a bean as hinted in the migration documentation:

```
  @Bean
  public SecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository() {
    return new DelegatingSecurityContextRepository(
        new RequestAttributeSecurityContextRepository(),
        new HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository()
    );
  }
```

Later on my security configuration was extended in a similar way:

```
  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http, 
        SecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository) throws Exception {
    
    http.
       ...
       .and().
        securityContext().
          securityContextRepository(securityContextRepository);

    return http.build();
  }
```

The autologin was fixed as shown below (the important line is saving the context in the repository):

```
@Override
  public void createAccount(UserRegistrationDTO userRegistrationDTO,
      HttpServletRequest request,
      HttpServletResponse response) {

    ...
   
    SecurityContextHolderStrategy securityContextHolderStrategy = SecurityContextHolder
        .getContextHolderStrategy();

    SecurityContext context = securityContextHolderStrategy.createEmptyContext();
    context.setAuthentication(authentication);
    securityContextHolderStrategy.setContext(context);

    securityContextRepository.saveContext(context, request, response);
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

If it stopped working after migrating to Spring Security 6, it is probably related to [require explicit save of the `SecurityContext`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/session-management.html#_require_explicit_saving_of_securitycontextrepository).

This means that you should save the context explicitly by calling the `SecurityContextRepository`:

```java
SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
context.setAuthentication(authentication);
SecurityContextHolder.setContext(context);
securityContextRepository.saveContext(request, response, context);
```

Where `securityContextRepository` usually is `HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository`.

Answer (score 3):

I was about to build a brand-new app using Spring Boot 3 / Spring 6.x,
and to master this topic I had to go through the following resources:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/session-management.html 
https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-security-architecture/ 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/authorize-http-requests.html

Plus in the code snippet https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/session-management.html#store-authentication-manually
is an error, instead of securityContextHolderStrategy.setContext(authentication); 
should be securityContextHolderStrategy.setContext(context);

as it is already fixed in version '6.0.3'.
BAU: Exception Handler, User, Role, Repo(s), Mapper, Validator, ...

Servlet or Rest Controller:

```
  @PostMapping(value = "/registration")
  public String postRegistration(@NonNull User user, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response
  ) throws UserValidatorException {
    userValidator.validate(user);
    userService.save(user);
    securityService.login(user, request, response);
    return "home";
  }
```

SecurityService of mine:

```
@Component
public class SecurityService {

  private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
  private final SecurityContextHolderStrategy securityContextHolderStrategy = SecurityContextHolder.getContextHolderStrategy();
  private final SecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository = new HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository();


  @Autowired
  public SecurityService(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
    this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
  }


  /**
   * Spring Security is fundamentally thread-bound, because it needs to make the current authenticated
   * principal available to a wide variety of downstream consumers. The basic building block is the
   * SecurityContext, which may contain an Authentication (and when a user is logged in it is an
   * Authentication that is explicitly authenticated). You can always access and manipulate the
   * SecurityContext through static convenience methods in SecurityContextHolder, which, in turn,
   * manipulate a ThreadLocal.
   */
  public Optional<String> getCurrentUserLogin() {
    final var securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
    final var authentication = securityContext.getAuthentication();
    if (authentication != null) {
      if (authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof final UserDetails userDetails) {
        return Optional.of(userDetails.getUsername());

      } else if (authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof final String userLogin) {
        return Optional.of(userLogin);

      }
    }
    return Optional.empty();
  }


  @Transactional
  public void login(
      User user
      , HttpServletRequest request
      , HttpServletResponse response
  ) {
    final var token = UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.unauthenticated(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword());
    final var authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(token);
    final var context = securityContextHolderStrategy.createEmptyContext();
    context.setAuthentication(authentication);
    securityContextHolderStrategy.setContext(context);
    securityContextRepository.saveContext(context, request, response);
  }

}
```

WebSecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

  private static final String[] ALLOWED_REALM_URLS = new String[]{"/", "/home", "/registration", "/login", "/logout"};
  private static final String[] ALLOWED_PUB_URLS = new String[]{"/pub/registration", "/pub/login"};

  private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
  private final AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;


  @Autowired
  public WebSecurityConfig(UserDetailsService userDetailsService, AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint) {
    this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    this.authenticationEntryPoint = authenticationEntryPoint;
  }

  @Bean
  public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
  }

  @Bean
  public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    return httpSecurity.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class)
        .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
        .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
        .and().build();
  }

  @Bean
  public CorsRegistry corsRegistry() {
    var corsRegistry = new CorsRegistry();
    corsRegistry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("*");
    return corsRegistry;
  }

  /**
   * Rest API under /auth requires authentication (/pub does not),
   * because authentication is required only for endpoints covered by .securityMatcher
   */
  @Bean
  @Order(1)
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChainAuth(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
        .csrf()

        .and()
        .cors()

        .and()
        .securityMatcher(antMatcher("/auth/**"))
        .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        )

        .build();
  }

  @Bean
  @Order(2)
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChainPub(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
        .csrf()

        .and()
        .cors()

        .and()
        .securityMatcher(antMatcher("/pub/**"))
        .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, ALLOWED_PUB_URLS).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().denyAll()
        )

        .exceptionHandling(exception -> exception
            .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
        )

        .build();
  }


  @Bean
  @Order(3)
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChainMvc(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
        .csrf()

        .and()
        .cors()

        .and()
        .securityMatcher(ALLOWED_REALM_URLS)
        .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, ALLOWED_REALM_URLS).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().denyAll()
        )

        .formLogin(form -> form
            .loginPage("/login")
        )

        .logout(logout -> logout
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
            .permitAll()
        )

        .rememberMe(me -> me
            .key("RememberMeKey")
            .tokenValiditySeconds(86400)
        )

        .sessionManagement(session -> session
            .maximumSessions(1)
        )

        .build();
  }

}
```

UserDetailsServiceImpl:

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

  private final UserRepo userRepo;


  public UserDetailsServiceImpl(UserRepo userRepo) {
    this.userRepo = userRepo;
  }


  @Override
  @Transactional(readOnly = true)
  public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    final var jpaUser = userRepo.findByUsername(username);
    if (jpaUser == null) {
      throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username not found.");
    }

    return User.builder()
        .username(jpaUser.getUsername())
        .password(jpaUser.getPassword())
        .authorities(StreamUtil.ofNullable(jpaUser.getRoles())
            .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()))
            .toList()
        )
        .build();
  }

}
```