# Invalid configuration that explicitly sets requireExplicitAuthenticationStrategy to true but implicitly requires it, under Spring Boot v3.0.4

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, java-17

I've got here Spring Boot Web application.

It was upgraded to the following set-up:

- Java 17
- Spring Boot 3.0.4
- Spring Security 6.0.2
- Jetty 11 server

When I start the application up, I get this line on the console:

- `Running with Spring Boot v3.0.4, Spring v6.0.6`

I am having issues with Spring security configuration.

The security configuration Java file comes next.

```
@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.DEFAULT_FILTER_ORDER)
@EnableMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecConfiguration {

    private final HouseUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;
    private final HouseShiftConfiguration dashShiftConfig;

    private final DBI dbi;
    private final AuditLogService auditLogService;

    @Autowired
    private CustomSecurityconfiguration customSecurityConfiguration;

    @Autowired
    public SecConfiguration(HouseUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService, DBI dbi, HouseShiftConfiguration dashShiftConfig, AuditLogService auditLogService) {
        this.customUserDetailsService = customUserDetailsService;
        this.dbi = dbi;
        this.dashShiftConfig = dashShiftConfig;
        this.auditLogService = auditLogService;
    }

    @Bean
    public HouseRedirectAuthenticationSuccessHandler houseRedirectAuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
        return new HouseRedirectAuthenticationSuccessHandler(dbi);
    }
  
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfiguration) throws Exception {
       return authConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        HttpSessionRequestCache requestCache = new HttpSessionRequestCache();
        requestCache.setMatchingRequestParameterName("continue");

        CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler csrfRequestHandler = new CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler();
        csrfRequestHandler.setCsrfRequestAttributeName("_csrf");// set the name of the attribute the CsrfToken will be populated on

        XorCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler xorCsrfRequestHandler = new XorCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler();
        xorCsrfRequestHandler.setCsrfRequestAttributeName("_csrf");// set the name of the attribute the CsrfToken will be populated on
        
        //csrf white list, when you don't want to use csrf, put your url here.
        String[] csrfWhiteList = {
                "/emailSender/**"
        };

        http
        .csrf((csrf) -> csrf.csrfTokenRequestHandler(csrfRequestHandler)).csrf((xorCsrf) -> xorCsrf.csrfTokenRequestHandler(xorCsrfRequestHandler)).csrf().ignoringRequestMatchers(csrfWhiteList) 
        .and() 
        .rememberMe().rememberMeServices(dashShiftConfig.tokenBasedRememberMeServicesCore())

        .and()
        .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth.dispatcherTypeMatchers(DispatcherType.FORWARD/*, DispatcherType.INCLUDE, DispatcherType.ASYNC, DispatcherType.ERROR, DispatcherType.REQUEST*/).permitAll()
        
        .requestMatchers("/accessDenied", "/security_check", "/img/*", "/js/*", "/css/*", "/?*", "/", "/login*").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().permitAll())
       
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/security_check")
                .failureUrl("/?r=fail")
                .failureHandler(HouseAuthFailureHandler())
                .successHandler(HouseRedirectAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
                .and()

        .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessHandler(customLogoutHandler())
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID","rm")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().invalidSessionUrl("/?r=invalidSessionUrlLogin")
  
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler());

        http
                .headers()
                .frameOptions().disable()
                .addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("X-FRAME-OPTIONS", "ALLOW-FROM https://www.secure-service.com"));

        http
                .headers()
                .xssProtection(xssProtection -> xssProtection.headerValue(XXssProtectionHeaderWriter.HeaderValue.ENABLED_MODE_BLOCK))
                .contentSecurityPolicy("form-action 'self'");

        http.sessionManagement((sessions) -> sessions.requireExplicitAuthenticationStrategy(true /*it requires true */)).sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1).sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry()).expiredUrl("/?r=sessionExpiredDuplicateLogin");
      
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
         
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(this.customUserDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(customSecurityConfiguration.passwordEncoder());
     
        return authProvider;
    }

   }
```

When I boot the application, I get this error:

```
09/03/2023 16:07:37.344 [restartedMain] WARN  o.s.b.w.s.c.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization -
 cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 
 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChains'
  parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'filterChain' defined in class path resource [co/age/house/component/security/SecConfiguration.class]: Failed to 
  instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'filterChain' threw exception with message: Invalid configuration that explicitly 
  sets requireExplicitAuthenticationStrategy to true but implicitly requires it due to the following properties being set: [maximumSessions = 1, invalidSessionUrl = /?r=invalidSessionUrlLogin]
```

**The stacktrace comes next:**

```
09/03/2023 16:07:37.380 [restartedMain] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChains' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'filterChain' defined in class path resource [co/age/house/component/security/SecConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'filterChain' threw exception with message: Invalid configuration that explicitly sets requireExplicitAuthenticationStrategy to true but implicitly requires it due to the following properties being set: [maximumSessions = 1, invalidSessionUrl = /?r=invalidSessionUrlLogin]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:817)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:769)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:133)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:481)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1408)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
       
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'filterChain' defined in class path resource [co/age/house/component/security/SecConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'filterChain' threw exception with message: Invalid configuration that explicitly sets requireExplicitAuthenticationStrategy to true but implicitly requires it due to the following properties being set: [maximumSessions = 1, invalidSessionUrl = /?r=invalidSessionUrlLogin]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:657)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:645)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1324)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1161)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
      
        ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'filterChain' threw exception with message: Invalid configuration that explicitly sets requireExplicitAuthenticationStrategy to true but implicitly requires it due to the following properties being set: [maximumSessions = 1, invalidSessionUrl = /?r=invalidSessionUrlLogin]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:171)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
        ... 41 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid configuration that explicitly sets requireExplicitAuthenticationStrategy to true but implicitly requires it due to the following properties being set: [maximumSessions = 1, invalidSessionUrl = /?r=invalidSessionUrlLogin]
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.SessionManagementConfigurer.shouldRequireExplicitAuthenticationStrategy(SessionManagementConfigurer.java:425)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.SessionManagementConfigurer.createSessionManagementFilter(SessionManagementConfigurer.java:435)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.SessionManagementConfigurer.configure(SessionManagementConfigurer.java:398)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.SessionManagementConfigurer.configure(SessionManagementConfigurer.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.configure(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:349)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:303)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:38)
```

This error is caused by this line:

```
http.sessionManagement((sessions) -> sessions.requireExplicitAuthenticationStrategy(true /*it requires true */))
```

If I set it back to Spring Security 5.8 defaults, which is to false:

```
http.sessionManagement((sessions) -> sessions.requireExplicitAuthenticationStrategy(false /*it requires true */))
```

I can boot, and run the Web app just fine.

Though I want to stick to Spring Security v6 configuration, which is setting it to true.

This is what the Spring documentation says about it:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8.0/migration/servlet/session-management.html

Is there a work around for this (so that to go along with Spring Security v6)?

Comment: what you are asking for is probably impossible. You are basically by setting the value to `true`, saying that spring doesnt need to check the session for every request. But then you have also set that maximum allowed sessions are to be 1, which means that spring must always check the session to be able to make sure there is only one session. So either you pick one or the other, you can't have both. The workaround is posted in your link, set the value to `false` and spring will check each request if there is more than one session.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Auto login after registration Spring Boot 3/Spring security 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75618616/auto-login-after-registration-spring-boot-3-spring-security-6)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.
I just removed `sessions.requireExplicitAuthenticationStrategy(true)` line while upgrading from 5.8 to 6.0.

As far as I understand, this strategy is `true` by default in Spring Security 6 (and `false` in Spring Security 5), so setting it explicitly to `true` in 5.8 was just to verify if (and how) your security configuration would work after 5 -> 6 upgrade.