# Problem with authenticationManager in securityFilterChain SpringBoot 3

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, authentication, security

As you can see in this photo im trying to add an authenticationManager in my .addFilter(new JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter()) but springboot doesnt let because im using the securityFilterChain method.

#############################################################################################

```
  @Configuration
  @EnableWebSecurity
   @EnableMethodSecurity

   public class ApplicationSecurityConfig {

     private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private final ApplicationUserService applicationUserService;
    @Autowired
    public ApplicationSecurityConfig(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder,
                                     ApplicationUserService applicationUserService) {
        this.passwordEncoder=passwordEncoder;
        this.applicationUserService = applicationUserService;
    }

    @Bean
        public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http

                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .addFilter(new JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/", "/index", "/css/*", "/js/*").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/api/**").hasRole(ApplicationUserRole.STUDENT.name())
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .build();
    }

    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        provider.setUserDetailsService(applicationUserService);
        return provider;
    }
}
```

############################################################################################

my class JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter is this ,

```
public class JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
                                                HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {

        try {
            UsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest = new ObjectMapper()
                    .readValue(request.getInputStream(), UsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationRequest.class);

            Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                authenticationRequest.getUsername(),
                authenticationRequest.getPassword()
            );
            Authentication authenticate = authenticationManager.authenticate(authentication);
            return authenticate;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
                                            HttpServletResponse response,
                                            FilterChain chain,
                                            Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {

        String key = "securesecuresecuresecuresecuresecuresecuresecuresecuresecure";
        String token = Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(authResult.getName())
                .claim("authorities",authResult.getAuthorities())
                .setIssuedAt(new Date())
                .setExpiration(java.sql.Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now().plusWeeks(2)))
                .signWith(Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(key.getBytes()))
                .compact();

        response.addHeader("Authorization","bearer " + token);
    }

}
```

Can anyone help me?? What should i do in order make it work in the new version of springboot??

Thanks anyway.

Im trying to pass the obstacle that was created due to different version of springboot and im believe that someone can help me to find a solution.

Answer (score -1):

Kindly check my recent Spring Boot 3 project:
https://github.com/thevarga04/ucimsa/blob/main/src/main/java/ucimsa/config/WebSecurityConfig.java

And in this post I elaborated on a few topics:
[Auto login after registration Spring Boot 3/Spring security 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75618616/auto-login-after-registration-spring-boot-3-spring-security-6/76017750#76017750)