# Spring Boot security configuration is always setting Anonymous Authentication despite having authenticated

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

I am trying to configure a Spring Boot backend to authenticate using session cookies, but without using form login. The way to log in will be through a REST API endpoint, but for some reason, even though I authenticate successfully, when accessing a protected endpoint, I see in the logs that the Security Context is being set to anonymous.  I have configured my filter chain like this:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
            .csrf(csrf->csrf.disable())
            .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED))
            .formLogin(loginConfig -> loginConfig.disable())
            .authenticationProvider(provider)
            .authorizeHttpRequests(reqs->
                    reqs.requestMatchers("/api/login").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/api/**").authenticated());
                    .anyRequest().permitAll());

    return http.build();

}
```

And my authenticate controller looks like this:

```
@PostMapping("/login")
public ResponseEntity<Object> login(@Valid @RequestBody LoginDto loginDto){
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginDto.getEmail(),loginDto.getPassword());
    try {
        var auth = authenticationManager.authenticate(token);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
        System.out.println("Auth result is: "+auth.isAuthenticated());
        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();

    }
}
```

I think I'm missing something pretty basic here but can't figure out what it is. I am using DaoAuthenticationProvider backed by PostgreSQL DB, and BCryptPassword encoder. Authentication works, but it seems Authorization isn't. Like my session is not being stored. Using SessionCreatePolicy.ALWAYS does not solve the issue. Please help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Auto login after registration Spring Boot 3/Spring security 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75618616/auto-login-after-registration-spring-boot-3-spring-security-6)

Comment: this is well documented for the SecurityContext in the docs, and not when reading outdated blogs/posts.

Comment: @Toerktumlare, if you know of better documentation for this I'd appreciate some links to it. I've tried to learn Spring Security through their docs but it's not intuitive.

Comment: not to be rude, but saying that something "isnt intuitive" isnt that constructive. There is a huge chapter named _Authentication Architecture_ that in detail explains the entire authentication process, all the steps, all the classes and their meanings. There is also en entire segment named _SecurityContextHolder_ https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/architecture.html#servlet-authentication-securitycontextholder i dont know how it can be more intuitive than that?

Comment: @Toerktumlare, not to be rude, either, but your original comment wasn't constructive either, as you did not really provide new information.  I will read through the link you provided now and see if I can learn anything that will help me.

Comment: i would suggest reading docs

Comment: @dur Your link and Toerktumlare's comments lead my down the path that ultimately helped me solve it. What I ended doing was adding: .addFilter(new SecurityContextPersistenceFilter()) to my SecurityFilterConfig, as this saves the trouble of having to manually save the context. I've done JWT based auth before, so I'm not unfamiliar with the basics of Spring Security, but it seems this step is necessary when using cookie based auth and not using formLogin.

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that authorization is not working properly because something is missing from the implementation of the UserDetailsService class. This is a sample implementation (probably, you have a similar implementation):

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final PasswordEncoder encoder;
    private final RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    User user = userRepository.getByEmail(username).orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found"));
    return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
            user.getEmail(),
            user.getPassword(),
            user.isEnabled(),
            getAuthorities(user.getRoles())

    }

    //and so on...

}
```

Comment: Yes, I have an implementation of UserDetailsService. I've debugged through my code and all of it is executing properly on authentication. But the session is still being assigned as anonymous on subsequent requests.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).